# How to get all constraint errors from a single query run that violates multiple constraints

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm using Memgraph and the Neo4j Driver and have encountered a problem with constraint exceptions. When executing a query that potentially violates multiple constraints, the system identifies only one constraint violation at a time.

If my query violates constraints on four different fields, the system only reports one violation per execution. Now I need to execute the query multiple times (at least four in this case) to identify and resolve all constraint violations.

Is there a method or a feature in Memgraph or the Neo4j Driver that allows identification of all violated constraints in a single query execution?